# Problem involving integration of ln, log with different base, e to the power log

Tags: integration

Does this problem have easy solution employing any integration technique?

Evaluate: $$\int\ln({\log_\pi {e^{\log_2  (x)}}}) dx$$
Or the integration techniques fall short to handle this kind of twisted problem. In that case how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Using the [change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base):

$$log_{\pi}e^{\log_2 x}=\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2 \ln \pi}$$

Because:
$$
\log_2 x=\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}=y
$$
and:
$$
\log_\pi e^y =\frac{\ln (e^y)}{\ln \pi}=\frac{y}{\ln \pi}
$$

But, after this, you have to use the [Logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) to find the primitive.

Comment: can you please elaborate how you got this which formulae did you use to arrive here?

Comment: I've added something.

Comment: great! I understood that. Apparently after that it is complicated it seems!

Comment: You can integrate by part but anyway you find an integral $\int \frac{1}{ln x} dx$ and this cannot be integrated with elementary functions.

Comment: thanks Emilio at least solving some part algebraically helps as another question is to differentiate it, simplifying it the way you did helps in finding derivative of this function